# List footer view doesn't appear if setListAdapter is called

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I am having a somewhat weird scenario building the UI for an Android application. Although I got to solve the error, I don't know the cause and I would like to understand why this is happening in order learn more about Android. I reproduced the scenario in a simple application:

Creating a new Hello World Android application adding this resources file under res/layout/footer_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Foo Bar" />
```

And using this Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(android.R.layout.list_content);

        ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.activity_list_item);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        View footer = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.footer_view, getListView(), false);
        getListView().addFooterView(footer);
    }

}
```

We get the following screen:

[image]

To my surprise I saw that the footer view, which is a TextView saying "Foo Bar", was missing. After some playing around I found out the solution was to move the "setListAdapter(adapter);" line to the end of the onCreate() method, or said differently, after adding the footer to the view.

Exploring a little further I found out the problem is the width, which is 0 if I have the adapter added before. Another solution was to indicate an explicit width other than match_parent.

Any clue why this happens? For me it'd be more intuitive that it didn't work if the adapter hadn't been added because the list may not be ready, but why would it not work if everything is prepared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that internally, if there are headers or footers, the adapter is wrapped inside another adapter.

So if you call `setAdapter` before adding the header and footer views, then the wrapping adapter is not aware of them.

If you leave `setAdapter` to the end, then the adapter that wraps your adapter knows about the headers/footers since those have already been added to the list.

See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView%28android.view.View%29):

> Add a fixed view to appear at the bottom of the list. If addFooterView
>   is called more than once, the views will appear in the order they were
>   added. Views added using this call can take focus if they want.
>
> Note: When first introduced, this method could only be called before
>   setting the adapter with setAdapter(ListAdapter). Starting with
>   KITKAT, this method may be called at any time. If the ListView's
>   adapter does not extend HeaderViewListAdapter, it will be wrapped with
>   a supporting instance of WrapperListAdapter.